# Infer property type from interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following interface:

```js
interface Person<T extends string> {
  name: T;
  sayHello: (name: T) => void;
}
```

How do I construct a new Person object without manually setting `T`, as such:

```js
const alice: Person = { // error: Generic type 'Person<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)
  name: 'Alice',
  sayHello: (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}`); // how to automatically infer name as "Alice"?
  },
};
```

---

To partially answer my own question, I could create a helper function to build the `Person` object, but that feels somewhat redundant:

```
const createPerson = <T extends string>(person: Person<T>): Person<T> => person;

const alice = createPerson({
  name: 'Alice',
  sayHello: (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`); // name is automatically inferred as "Alice"
  },
});
```

---

Is what I want from the first example not possible at all or am I just misunderstading some fundamental concept?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (but I really wish it was).

Comment: You want https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794 which is not a feature yet. The helper function is the standard workaround. See the linked q/a for more info.